# How to add next row start date date as the previous row end date?

Tags: azure-synapse

[image: DataImage]

I want to calculate end date of trans_num '1' based on start date of trans_num '2' in SQL. End date is Start date of trans_num '2' - 1. How can I do that? Please refer to image for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` functions in Azure SQL Data Warehouse to refer to different rows.  More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples--and-).

I can get the right answer with your limited set of test data but I'm sure your test data or explanation of the rules is complete enough.  Anyway, try something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    ID          INT NOT NULL,
    StartDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate     DATE NOT NULL,
    TRANS_NUM   INT NOT NULL,
    Veh_Num     INT NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    HEAP
)
GO


INSERT INTO #tmp ( ID, StartDate, EndDate, TRANS_NUM, Veh_Num )
SELECT 10001, '12 Feb 2018', '12 Feb 2019', 1, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '12 Feb 2018', '12 Feb 2019', 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '16 Feb 2018', '12 Feb 2019', 2, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '16 Feb 2018', '12 Feb 2019', 2, 2
GO


SELECT *,
    ISNULL(
        DATEADD( day, -1, LEAD( StartDate, 1 ) 
            OVER( PARTITION BY ID, Veh_num ORDER BY StartDate ) 
            ),
        EndDate) AS newEndDate
FROM #tmp
ORDER BY TRANS_NUM, Veh_Num
```

If this does not work for you, please provide a more complete set of test data with other scenarios and a fuller explanation of the rules.  Also, supplying a schema and data in the form of SQL (as per my script) rather than a screenprint helps a lot.